# unable to find pair of same liking in xml document

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<person name = "fred"/>
<person name ="sue"/>
<person name = "jill" />
<person name = "khan"/>
<cheese name ="camembert"/>
<cheese name="roquefort"/>
<liking person="fred" cheese="camembert"/>
<liking person="fred" cheese="roquefort"/>
<liking person ="sue" cheese ="roquefort"/>
<liking person ="jill" cheese = "camembert" />
<liking person ="khan" cheese = "camembert"/>
```

I did a lot of effort to find pair of people who like same cheese in above xml document using FLOWR. 
but I am unable to make logic could any please help me making a logic to find pair person who like same cheese, pair should not  repeat.

Comment: Leos Literak  i need to try no option

Answer (score 2):

Again only a sketch, as this has a (cheesy) smell of programming assignments:

- You want to find pairs by cheese type, so loop over the different kinds of cheese.
- For each cheese, find a person that likes it.
- And for each person, find a following person that also likes it.

By only finding following persons, you will prevent duplicates.

---

Update: After you posted your try:

```
for $x in doc("cheese.xml")/cheeseEaters/cheese
for $y in doc("cheese.xml")/cheeseEaters/liking[@cheese = $x/@name]
for $z in $y[@cheese = $y/@cheese]
return $z/@person
```

As I think was close enough, that's what I was doing:

```
for $cheese in //cheese/@name
for $person1 in //liking[@cheese=$cheese]
for $person2 in $person1/following-sibling::liking[@cheese=$cheese]
return element pair {
  $person1/@person/data(),
  $person2/@person/data()
}
```

It need minor modifications to load the data from where you've got it, but this'll be easy for you. Some remarks to your code:

- Always use descriptive variable names. `$x` and `$y` will confuse you next time reading the code, and everybody else that will ever look at it.
- Looping over the cheese kinds and "first" persons that like them seems right.
- The third for-loop needs to search the whole data set again, you're only looping over the single item of the second loop. And make sure to use `following-sibling`!
- Finally, you need to return both names, of course.

Comment: for $x in doc("cheese.xml")/cheeseEaters/cheese

for $y in doc("cheese.xml")/cheeseEaters/liking[@cheese = $x/@name] 

for $z in $y[@cheese = $y/@cheese]  I am using these three loops to find smiler cheese liking but i think something is wrong in .?

Comment: I have find list of cheese likes persons but how to get similar likeness one together, because when I use third for loop over list of cheese likes i find it give me wrong answer .

Comment: Already updated my answer. General hints: Posting code in comments is usually not the best possible way, as it's hardly readable. Better edit the question instead. And if there is a problem, also describe what's going wrong: with wrong output and expected output. Show us what you tried, and that you care, and you will usually receive an exact solution to your problem in short time (and upvotes instead of downvotes, the community here really wants to see _some_ own effort before asking!).

Comment: Jens Erat my problem is solved. great help you did Thanks as well I learn many things for your post

Comment: Great to hear that. If it did, you might want to select the answer as accepted. Have a look at the [FAQ].